# use Qt to find which editor is installed on a Linux machine

Tags: linux, qt

In my C++/Qt program I would like to know which text editor is available on user's Linux machine so that I can use it to open a text file from my program. There are several widely used editors such as `gedit`, `kate` and a few more so I would like to check these. My naive intention was to use `QProcess` in combinations with `command -v foobar` as in [How to check if a program exists from a Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/how-to-check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script) but unfortunately this does not seem to be doing what I expect. I hoped that the exit codes could indicate the result.

`qDebug() << QProcess::execute("command -v kate") << QProcess::execute("command -v gedit");`

... but the processes did not even started and the line returned `-2 -2`.

Is there any way to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run it through sh, [setProcessChannelMode](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#setProcessChannelMode) to get error of the child of sh command :

```
QProcess chkexists;
chkexists.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);
chkexists.start("sh", QStringList()<<"-c"<<"command -v kate");
chkexists.waitForFinished();
if(chkexists.exitCode()==0){
////editor exists
}
```

Comment: I tried, I call `waitForFinished()` and then I query the exit code. But then it returns exit code 0 even for editors which are not installed.

Comment: @V.K.  just edited my answer. you should set process channel mode to merged.

Comment: To make the solution complete, I then need to call `chkexists.waitForFinished();` and then compare `chkexists.exitCode() == 0;` which returns `true`/`false` indicating whether the program is installed or not. This works in my case very well.